# Understanding routing with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make a stupid simple CMS for one of my clients using rails. I generated scaffolding for `Page` and have been successful at creating and rendering those pages, however, the routing is ugly.

Right now, if I want to view the home page, I get a url like this: `example.com/pages/1`

**I'd like to accomplish 2 things:**

How do I set the routing so that `example.com` automagically grabs the page named "home"

and

How do I set the routing so that `example.com/page/page_name` performs a

`@page = Page.find_by name: 'page_name'`

Comment: Instead of trying to reinvent the wheel, have a look at https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/content_management_systems As you need something simple, Radiant might be a good fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1:

> How do I set the routing so that example.com automagically grabs the page named "home"

In `routes.rb:

```
root :to => '[controller]#[action]' 
#'pages#home' for example, if your home page is in `pages_controller`
# and uses the `home` action
```

Q2:

> How do I set the routing so that example.com/page/page_name performs a
>   @page = Page.find_by name: 'page_name'

```
match '/page/:name', :to => 'pages#some_name', :as => :some_name
```

this would generate the following in `$rake routes`:

```
 some_name    /page/:name(.:format)  pages#some_name
```

when you link to (or redirect, or otherwise access) this page, you'd write

```
link_to "click this link!", some_name_path(@SomeModel.some_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish the first thing you need to open the file routes.rb which is in the config folder and add the following:

```
root to: "home#index"
```

I'm assuming you have a controller named home which contains a method called index and this is the one that displays the home page.
If you want to make it the same as example.com/pages then you would have to use

```
root to: "pages#index"
```

to make a general rule you need to use

```
root to: "controller#method"
```

Don't forget to remove the index.html from the public folder too.
I recommend you make the blog application presented here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html
It can help you understand more.

Comment: and for the second thing, use the friendly_id gem

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that assumes your controller is named `pages_controller` instead of `page_controller`.

Add these routes in `config/routes.rb`:

```
root to: 'pages#show', page_name: 'home'
get 'pages/:page_name', to: 'pages#show'
```

For the controller `app/controllers/pages_controller.rb`:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @page = Page.find_by(name: params[:page_name])
  end

end
```

Note: In rails4 the `find_by` dynamic finders have been deprecated... so if you're app is on 4 you should look into updating them. [These docs have further details](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations).

Also, if you're just trying to get static looking urls then I would definitely go with [Marian Theisen's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/907986/marian-theisen) suggestion and use [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id).